# Divide in query and error Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to write this query (all of the fields are int):

```
select SUM(Service.discount+((Service.price*Factor.discount)/(Factor.amount-Factor.discount)))
```

But sometimes I get this error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Other times I get this error:

> Divide by zero error encountered.

How can I rewrite this query to avoid these errors?

//I Use this but agan overflow

```
select case  when(Factor.amount-Factor.discount)<>0 then 
Service.discount+((Service.price*Factor.discount)/(Factor.amount-Factor.discount)) 
else
    Service.discount
end
from Factor inner join Service on Factor.code=Service.factorCode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arithmetic overflow: don't use sum at all, take SUM off and take the brackets off either end.
Divide by zero: see Jonny's answer (I think he means //something as in whatever you want to do when factor.amount-factor.discount is zero....)

so maybe:

```
select case when discount2 <> 0 then discount+((price*discount)/(discount2)) else
discount+(price*discount) end FROM SERVICE
```

Comment: I edited the question.write a query like your answer but again occur overflow error

Comment: The aritmetic overflow implies that the resultant number is bigger than int, could this be possible (max value for int is 2,147,483,647)?

Comment: select case  when(Factor.discount)<>0 then min(Service.discount)+((min(Service.price)*min(Factor.discount))/(min(Factor.discount))) end from Factor inner join Service on Factor.code=Service.factorCode - does this give any arithmetic overflow?

Comment: I change type of column from int to float and ok

Comment: Thanks @russ, I've changed the line to use the right type of comment for SQL.

Comment: Hi Jonny, if you see my answer below, I've suggested that user3780058 converts the result set to float or decimal rather than changing the column datatypes as he suggests above.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
CASE (Factor.amount-Factor.discount)
  WHEN 0
    -- choose the result when Factor.amount-Factor.discount = 0 and replace this line
  ELSE 
    SUM(Service.discount+((Service.price*Factor.discount)/
      (Factor.amount-Factor.discount)))
END
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN (Factor.amount-Factor.discount) <> 0
THEN
CONVERT(FLOAT,Service.discount+((Service.price*Factor.discount)/(Factor.amount-
Factor.discount))) 
ELSE
Service.discount
END
FROM Factor INNER JOIN  Service ON Factor.code=Service.factorCode
```

It might be better to decide how many decimal places you want to see:

```
CONVERT(decimal(10,2),Service.discount+((Service.price*Factor.discount)/(Factor.amount-Factor.discount)))
```